# Where to define the locales for language that I want to support in grails?

Tags: grails, internationalization

I used the

```
<form method="get">
  <g:localeSelect name="lang" value="${locale}"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Change locale"/>
</form>
```

to change the language for my website.
[image: Too much languages in the list]

But where can I define which languages does appear in the select-list? Currently there are about 50 languages specified, but I just want to have english, german, italian and french. But I don't know where to specify it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Grails `localeSelect` tag is implemented as shown below. As you can see, the `localeSelect` tag always uses all available locales, retrieved using `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`.

```
 /**
 * A helper tag for creating locale selects.<br/>
 *
 * eg. &lt;g:localeSelect name="myLocale" value="${locale}" /&gt;
 *
 * @emptyTag
 *
 * @attr name REQUIRED The name of the select
 * @attr value The set locale, defaults to the current request locale if not specified
 */
Closure localeSelect = { attrs ->
    attrs.from = Locale.getAvailableLocales()
    attrs.value = (attrs.value ?: RCU.getLocale(request))?.toString()
    // set the key as a closure that formats the locale
    attrs.optionKey = { it.country ? "${it.language}_${it.country}" : it.language }
    // set the option value as a closure that formats the locale for display
    attrs.optionValue = {it.country ? "${it.language}, ${it.country},  ${it.displayName}" : "${it.language}, ${it.displayName}" }

    // use generic select
    out << select(attrs)
}
```

You can easily create your own tag to select a locale based on the Grails `selectLocale` code and the Grails [manual on creating your own tags](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#taglibs).

The code below uses either a list of `availableLocales` passed to the tag as an attribute or a list of `availableLocales` found in the `session`. The rest of the tag code is exactly the same is the Grails original `localeSelect` tag. And you can also customize the order of the languages if you expect one language to be used most often.

```
class LanguageTagLib {

    static namespace = "lang"  

    Closure myLocaleSelect = { attrs ->
        attrs.from = attrs.availableLocales ?: session.availableLocales ?: []
        attrs.value = (attrs.value ?: RCU.getLocale(request))?.toString()
        // set the key as a closure that formats the locale
        attrs.optionKey = { it.country ? "${it.language}_${it.country}" : it.language }
        // set the option value as a closure that formats the locale for display
        attrs.optionValue = {it.country ? "${it.language}, ${it.country},  ${it.displayName}" : "${it.language}, ${it.displayName}" }

        // use generic select
        out << g.select(attrs)
    }
}
```

In your `.gsp` template you can now use `<lang:myLocaleSelect ... />` to include the locale selector.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried it but instead of a select-box I see the html-text "<select name="myLocale" id="myLocale" > <option value="de" selected="selected" >de, German</option> <option value="en" >en, English</option> <option value="fr" >fr, French</option> <option value="it" >it, Italian</option> </select>" on my website.

Comment: And you implemented and used it as a Grails tag in a GSP?

Comment: In main.gsp: <g:myLocaleSelect name="lang" value="${locale}"/>
I create a new TagLib extending From 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.FormTagLib' and copied your sample code in it.

Comment: You do not need to extend FormTagLib, simply create a file with name ending in TagLib in the grails-app/taglib folder.

Comment: ok I figured it out. There was a "static defaultEncodeAs = 'html'" defined on the top of TagLib-Class which I had to remove.

Comment: I need the extend in case of the "select" which is defined in FormTagLib.

Comment: I updated the code to use g.select(...) instead of select(...).